# Кликать по родительской view

Tags: java, android

Раньше использовал такую схему для нажатия на элемент целиком:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(LanguageViewHolder personViewHolder, final int position) 
personViewHolder.languageName.setText(languages.get(position).name);
((View) personViewHolder.languageName.getParent()).setOnClickListener(view -> listener.onRVItemClick(position));
}
```

Сейчас немного поменял структуру и в методе onClick знаю только как по id кликать:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case languages:
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Пробовал в switch обращаться к v.Parent() но не получается довести до ума. 
Основная идея не только по id а по всей вьюшке где находится данная id.

Comment: Не очень понятно что вам нужно.. Возможно что-то типа этого: `holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(this)`?

Comment: Листенер нужно вешать на каждую view, для которой хотите обрабатывать клик.

Comment: @eugeneek ну вообще то вроде как нет, можно и через `getParent` обращаться, чтобы не прописывать одно и то же нажатие на все view которые содержаться в одной xml. И автор так раз таки это делает в верхем участке кода, так понимаю трудность вся заключается в переносе этого же функционала в метод `onClick()`?

Comment: @Morozov В коде листенер как раз на parent и вешается, а не на вью, внутри этого родителя. Если делать способом, который вы предлагаете,  выполнится код и для той вью на которую кликнули и для родителя. А чтобы избежать этого, нужны доп проверки. Вы считаете, что лучше костылить через `getParent()`, чем пользоваться нормальным способом?

Comment: Я не говорю для каждой вью делать отдельный листенер. Я только говорю, что нужно вешать листенер на каждую вью, для которой нужна обработка кликов. И тогда никаких проблем с определением вью по id, в принципе, не будет.

Comment: @eugeneek да, я тебя понял, но всё равно если везде по нажатию одно и то же действие, то код будет избыточным.

Comment: @Morozov Если одно и тоже действие, то вешается один листенер и только на родителя. А с `getParent()` это действие выполнится дважды. Так что тоже не агрумент.

Comment: @eugeneek что значит выполнится дважды? до этого обращался к parent, и всё работало корректно. Сейчас проблема вызвать его в методке onClick также как я вызывал его в onBindViewHolder.

Comment: Добавьте полный код адаптера для второго случая. И что вы хотите получить в итоге? Обрабатывать отдельно клик на родителя и отдельно на элемент внутри него?